# jQuery UI datepicker with manual entry and dynamic min-date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a few datepickers on my page, which can be filled by picker or by manual entry. There are a few rules that should work on these datepickers, but I have no idea how to solve this dynamically.

**Problem 1**
  Date 2 should not be before Date 1. Date 3 should not be before 1 and 2.
  This works for the datepicker at the moment, but not for the manual input. If the date is entered manually and is before the min-date, the field should be left empty.

**Problem 2**
  If the first date changes (to an earlier date as before), the min-date for the second date should be updated as well.
  The same applies to third date picker.

There can be 1-x datepickers on that page!

```js
let d = new Date();
let nextValidDate = d.getDate() + "." + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "." + d.getFullYear();

$(document).on("blur change", ".datepicker", function () {
    nextValidDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
});

$(document).on('focus', '.datepicker',
    function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            firstDay: 1,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            minDate: nextValidDate
        });

        $(this).datepicker('show');
    });


$(document).on('blur', '.datepicker', function () {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
        parseInputDate(this);
    }
});



function parseInputDate(elm) {
    var currDate = new Date(),
        monDt = (('0' + currDate.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2) + ('0' + currDate.getDate()).slice(-2)), // get current month+date to compare
        inputVal = $(elm).val().match(/\d{2}/gi); // split date components into array of [dd,mm,yy,yy]

    // another date validation, by comparing parameters and date object result 
    var isValidDate = function (yyyy, mm, dd) {
        var dt = new Date(yyyy, parseInt(mm, 10) - 1, dd);
        return (dt.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) == yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    }

    if (inputVal != null && inputVal.length >= 2) {
        var year = currDate.getFullYear();

        if (monDt > (inputVal[1] + inputVal[0])) year++;
        // generate formatted text based on date component count
        // add date validation to catch invalid dates using (new Date('yyyy-mm-dd')).getTime() which will return NaN on invalid date

        var result = (inputVal.length == 2 && isValidDate(year, inputVal[1], inputVal[0]) && inputVal[0] + '.' + inputVal[1] + '.' + year) ||
            (inputVal.length == 3 && isValidDate('20' + inputVal[2], inputVal[1], inputVal[0]) && inputVal[0] + '.' + inputVal[1] + '.20' + inputVal[2]) ||
            (inputVal.length == 4 && isValidDate(inputVal[2] + inputVal[3], inputVal[1], inputVal[0]) && inputVal[0] + '.' + inputVal[1] + '.' + inputVal[2] + inputVal[3]) ||
            ''; // set empty on invalid dates

        $(elm).val(result);
        nextValidDate = result;
    } else {
        $(elm).val('')
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <label for="date1">Date 1:</label>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="date2">Date 2:</label>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date2">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="date3">Date 3:</label>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

We can setup your code like so:

```js
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';

  function getDate(el) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, el.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }
    return date;
  }

  function checkMinDate(el) {
    var date = getDate(el);
    var minDate = $(el).datepicker("option", "minDate");
    var test;
    try {
      test = (date >= minDate);
    } catch (error) {
      test = false;
    }
    return test;
  }

  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    firstDay: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: dateFormat,
    minDate: 0
  }).on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var td = getDate(this);
    var dpid = $(this).attr("id");
    var dpi = parseInt(dpid.slice(dpid.indexOf("-") + 1));
    $("#date-" + (dpi + 1)).prop("disabled", false).datepicker("option", {
      minDate: td,
      defaultDate: td
    });
    if (!checkMinDate(this)) {
      this.value = "";
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  $(".datepicker:not(:eq(0))").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="date-wrapper">
  <div>
    <label for="date1">Date 1:</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date-1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="date2">Date 2:</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date-2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="date3">Date 3:</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date-3">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="date3">Date 4:</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date-4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="date3">Date 5:</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date-5">
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe this meets your criteria:

- The former date field should be less than or "before" the current date field.
- All previous dates should be less than this date field.
- If the a date changes, the min-date for the following dates should be updated as well.

The function `getDate()` receives an element and detects if it contains a date in String format (based on a date format) and return a Date object equal to that date or `null`.

The function `checkMinDate()` is to help us detect a manual entry dates. It checks the date entered manually against the minDate value. If it is greater than or equal to `minDate` it will return true. If it is less than `minDate` it will return false.

In our `change` callback, we use `.preventDefault()` to stop the current action. This is helpful for type events where we want to test what was entered. We can later return `true` or `false` to allow the event to progress. If `checkMinDate` is not true, we can clear the the value and return false.

Hope that helps!

Comment: that contains a few nice ideas, thank you. But I definitly have to include the parseDate function from my given sample to your code. Have to find out, how..